# Using hardhat with Windows

Tags: truffle, hardhat

Can anyone break down how to successfully set up a hardhat project on windows? I keep running into the HH12 error:
"Error HH12: Trying to use a non-local installation of Hardhat, which is not supported.
Please install Hardhat locally using npm or Yarn, and try again."

My understanding is that it is a Windows problem, but I haven't found any comprehensive instructions to solve this error. I've tried all the solutions I found online, but none work.

Any tips?
Thanks!

Comment: start a new npm project. with `npm init -y`and then run `npm install --save-dev hardhat`

Comment: You can just start from my [hardhat-template](https://github.com/paulrberg/hardhat-template).

Answer (score 0):

When I run `npm install --save-dev hardhat` I also get a peer dependency issue. Anyone able to solve the issue?

```
Conflicting peer dependency: @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers@2.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers
npm ERR!   peer @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers@"^2.0.0" from @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle@2.0.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle
npm ERR!     dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle@"^2.0.3" from the root project
```

Comment: This just means you didnt install it locally before and there are some conflicts in your node modules tree. 

Easiest option is just to move your project to a different directory which is not in the same structure of the node_modules directory and start again

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is legacy deps issue. The ethers library is sometimes conflicting.

Use command `npm install --save-dev hardhat --legacy-peer-deps`

`--legacy-peer-deps`: ignore all peer dependencies when installing, in the style of npm version 4 through version 6.

Other solution is to probably use `yarn` instead of `npm`.